# Reading Local Entry (XML,URL) in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2

I have configured below two local entry in WSO2 WSB4.9.0 how can I read the node values in proxy or sequence.

**In-Line XML Local Entry**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <localEntry key="test" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
      <list>
        <flag>a</flag>
        <path>b</path>
      </list>
    </localEntry>
```

and

**Source URL Entry**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<localEntry key="sample" src="file:/C:/Apache24/bin/ApacheMonitor" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

If the entry is in the filesystem, you can use:

```
<property name="testProp" expression="get-property('test')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

and

```
<property name="sampleProp" expression="get-property('sample')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

If you want to get access to the values inside XML set OM type:

```
<property name="testProp" expression="get-property('test')" scope="default" type="OM"/> 
<log level="custom">
    <property expression="$ctx:testProp" name="FullValue" />
    <property expression="$ctx:testProp//tt:flag" name="flagValue" xmlns:tt="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
    <property expression="$ctx:testProp//tt:path" name="pathValue" xmlns:tt="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
 </log>
```

My full proxy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="testProxy6"
       transports="https http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
        <property name="testProp" expression="get-property('test')" scope="default" type="OM"/> 
        <log level="custom">
            <property expression="$ctx:testProp" name="FullValue" />
            <property expression="$ctx:testProp//tt:flag" name="flagValue" xmlns:tt="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
            <property expression="$ctx:testProp//tt:path" name="pathValue" xmlns:tt="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"/>
         </log>     
        <respond/>  
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
          <log level="full">
             <property value="SEQUENCE: " name="OUT"/>
          </log>      
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

My local entry in file test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <localEntry key="test" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
      <list>
        <flag>a</flag>
        <path>b</path>
      </list>
    </localEntry>
```

My log output:

```
[2016-05-11 12:21:30,999]  INFO - LogMediator FullValue = <list xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <flag>a</flag>
        <path>b</path>
      </list>, flagValue = a, pathValue = b
```

Comment: But how do I get to node values <flag>a</flag> and <path>b</path> with above option it returns full xml entry.

Comment: Edit my response with the changes you requested.

Comment: Getting empty result

Comment: Getting empty result - FullValue=null , flagValue= , pathValue=

Comment: do you try with the inline entry?

Comment: I am using VFS proxy.

Comment: <inSequence>
      <property expression="get-property('test')" name="testProp"
        scope="default" type="OM"/>
      <log level="custom">
        <property expression="$ctx:testProp" name="FullValue"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:testProp//tt:flag" name="flagValue"/>
        <property expression="$ctx:testProp//tt:path" name="pathValue"/>
      </log>
    </inSequence>

Comment: the namespace you have mentioned in the property vanishing when I save the project. And I get below error

Comment: Evaluation of the XPath expression $ctx:testProp//tt:flag resulted in an error

Comment: Can you please share a VFS proxy example. I know its more or less the same but I do not know why the configuration you have suggested does not work for me.

Comment: @dilgates The error may because of the missing xpath. if you go to the source view again after saving the proxy and save again esb-ui miss the xpath, I think its a bug in the UI. What you can do is don't edit after a successful change.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to obtain values from an xml in a local entry, first of all you should have to get the xml content into a property and set its type to OM as below.

```
<property expression="get-property('xmlLocalEntrySample')" name="xmlTest" scope="default" type="OM"/>
```

Now from the message context you can read the property values like this. Here **$ctx** is the prefix for Synapse Message-Context properties and gets a property at the default scope using this. If you log the values of **testFlagA** and **testPath** you can see **a** and **b** print in the console respectively.

```
<property expression="$ctx:xmlTest//*[local-name()='flag']" name="testFlagA"/>
<property expression="$ctx:xmlTest//*[local-name()='path']" name="testPath"/>
```

Comment: Getting empty result - testFlagA = , testPath =

Answer (score 0):

For me get-property does not work for local entries, while xslt mediator works well . ie6.4

Comment: Works well or is a solution?

Comment: I am stating that for me get-properry does not work while xslt key=.   Is functional.  i.e. the local entry is configured ok and get-property dont work.